# PHP, how to make a function catch, catch PDOExceptions

Tags: php, function, exception, methods, try-catch

Can you have a method throw any exceptions that occurs within it's method body?  I want to automatically 'throw' any PDO related exceptions without always having to use 'try/catch' blocks within a function/method.

Example:

```
function testExcption($a..) throws PDOException{
   // PDO related code here.
}
```

So can I 'throw' and exception at the function/method declaration level and without any try/catch blocks?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to avoid always having to write 'try/catch' because I only care for the PDO related exceptions that can occur within those functions/methods.  I have lots of methods/functions and I'm tired of using 'try/catch' all the time for PDO error handling, and again I only care for the PDO exceptions in those functions/methods.  Does that make sense?

**EDIT**

Is there a way to get PDO errors w/o try/catch blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are mixing things. **Throwing** exceptions is done without any `try/catch` statment. Throwing Exceptions is as easy as:

```
function nonsensefunc(){
    throw new Exception('<Description of Error>');
}
```

On the other side, when calling you function, you have to use `try/catch`, you are **catching** them.

So what happens, when you do not catch the errors? The Exception is thrown a level higher and finally is printed out. Mostly it triggers an abort in PHP and stops the rest of the script.

So what is your expected behaviour? The only way of doing other thing as the default behaviour (printing the error and stopping) is to catch it.

Comment: No, I think your mixing things or confused.  I simply want only PDO exceptions to be caught within a method/function W/O using any try/catch blocks, as those are the only exceptions I specically want to handle.  In java you can throw an exception at the method declaration level, is that possible in php?

Comment: You never throw errors at declaration level! You just saying the compiler, that there **could** be this kind of error. Nothing more. Throwing is done, when the error occurs. The error is then thrown a level higher in the callstack, when its not catched there, it is thrown higher, etc. Finally the core will handle it (stopping the script) The same as in Java.

Comment: Ok, so if that's the case, is there a way to catch the exception for further handling without try/catch blocks?

Comment: you can wrap your whole script in one giant `try/catch` block, but I don't think it will help much, because the same issue woul occour, that you have to stop at the moment a error occours. If you want to preceed with the script, you have to locally catch the error and somehow react to it...

Comment: so in the event your custom throw exception is thrown, how do i get the error itself for further handling w/o try catch blocks?

Comment: Im only asking because I have a lot of try/catch blocks in my script and I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Whats wrong with them? As I said, when you doing a few things wich could throw an error, you could make the `try`-block larger and put multiple things in it.. But if they get too large, then there is no reasonable error handling possible.

Comment: ok, how about this.  Is there a way to get PDO errors w/o try/catch?